# How to find the location of missing values in a Data Frame in Python

Tags: python

Hi I have a data frame test that has missing values in one column test1.  I need to find out where the missing values are located. I also need to know how many values are missing in the column test1. For example I ran the command pd.isnull(test.test1).  This returns the output below.

```
0  FALSE
1  TRUE
2  FALSE
3  TRUE
4  FALSE
```

From this I can see the locations of missing values are index 1 and 3 and the count of missing values is 2.

What else do I need to add to my original statement to return this? i.e [1,3] and count of missing values 2.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question, this should work:

```
test.test1[test.test1 != test.test1].index.values
```